# Search for string in one column using strings from another column in another dataframe in R

Tags: r

I have 2 dataframes (both dataframes have 1 column each) and I want to search for strings present in the 1st column in the 1st dataframe for their presence in each row in the 2nd column of the other dataframe. If present, return the string value in a new column ("String") and a boolean column ("Match"). I tried a few commands like grepl and stringr but could not make it work. Thanks!

Sample below:

1st Dataframe

| SName |
| --- |
| svc1 |
| svc123 |
| svc567 |

2nd Dataframe

| Description |
| --- |
| - ls svc368 -@#@# |
| mkdir test svc #*-/ |
| mkdir df2 svc123 #*-/ |
| mkdir random svc1 #*-/ |
| mkdir test svc1 *&%^$%$ |
| mkdir fr svc567 *&%@ |
| mkdir 82 svc56 *&??// |
| mkdir kol svc *& |

Result desired:

| Description | Match | String |
| --- | --- | --- |
| - ls svc368 -@#@# | No |  |
| mkdir test svc #*-/ | No |  |
| mkdir df2 svc123 #*-/ | Yes | svc123 |
| mkdir random svc1 #*-/ | Yes | svc1 |
| mkdir test svc1 *&%^$%$ | Yes | svc1 |
| mkdir fr svc567 *&%@ | Yes | svc567 |
| mkdir 82 svc56 *&??// | No |  |
| mkdir kol svc *& | No |  |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to form a regex alternation of the terms in the first dataframe.  Then use `grepl` and `sub` to generate the output columns.

```r
regex <- paste0("\\b(", paste(df1$SName, collapse="|"), ")\\b")
df2$match <- ifelse(grepl(regex, df2$Description), "Yes", "No")
df2$String <- ifelse(grepl(regex, df2$Description),
                     sub(paste0(".*", regex, ".*"), "\\1", df2$Description),
                     "")
df2

            Description match String
1     - ls svc368 -@#@#    No       
2   mkdir test svc #*-/    No       
3 mkdir df2 svc123 #*-/   Yes svc123
...
```